# Remove part of the column name of a dataframe using a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe "counts" and I would like to change the name of the second column using a regular expression because I have multiple files with this "extra information", so I have:

```
| GeneID |  /home/rmachado/Biotec/ARJNA231684/mapa_fin_starterar/SRR1212121_mapped.bamAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam   |
| -------- | -------------- |
|  Ciclev10010164m.g.v1.0    | 2            |
|  Ciclev10007306m.g.v1.0    | 647            |
|  Ciclev10009318m.g.v1.0   | 39            |
|  Ciclev...   | ...           |
|  Ciclev10007306m.g.v1.0    | 112            |
```

I tried with the following code with no success:

```
for col in counts1:
  counts1.rename(columns={col:col.upper().replace("/home/rmachado/Biotec/ARJNA231684/mapa_fin_starterar/SRR1212121_mapped.bamAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam","SRR[\d]{6}")},inplace=True)
```

How can I obtain a df with the following format?

```
| GeneID |  SRR1212121   |
| -------- | -------------- |
|  Ciclev10010164m.g.v1.0    | 2            |
|  Ciclev10007306m.g.v1.0    | 647            |
|  Ciclev10009318m.g.v1.0   | 39            |
|  Ciclev...   | ...           |
|  Ciclev10007306m.g.v1.0    | 112            |
```

Comment: can you post the data as dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'((?<=/)SRR\d+|^[^/]+$)', expand=False)
```

regex:

```
(?<=/)SRR\d+  # match SDD + digits if preceded by "/"
^[^/]+$       # else match full string if it doesn't contain "/"
```

Comment: Thank you mozway! That's the answer that I looking for :D